Windows 11 64bit, please how can i fix issues

Firefox: when right-click on a link goes direct to the page instead of given me the options

Windows 11 keeps rearranging the desktop icons, i tried all below methods to fix it but failed:


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVQUCbKPaMk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZ9Nbvlfseg
https://support.lenovo.com/ie/en/solutions/ht504726-how-to-keep-desktop-icons-from-rearranging-after-reboot-in-windows-10
https://www.isunshare.com/windows-8/4-ways-to-open-local-group-policy-editor-on-windows-8-8.1.html
https://www.isunshare.com/windows-8/prevent-changing-desktop-icons-on-windows-8-8.1.html

How fix blank white icons on desktop, i tried all below methods but failed:
delete the icon cache then restart explorer
disable tablet mode
using DISM: DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

